# Can a system restore reinstall uninstalled programs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, system-restore

My pc has starting acting weird lately. I ran scan using Nod32, malware bytes. It did detect some viruses but my PC's behaviour doesn't change. When I use Adobe reader X it doesn't find the the word given for the search and I accidently Lost my Office 2010.

I am thinking that system restore can solve these issues and reinstall Office 2010. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Windows automatically makes restore points now and then such as when installing critical updates. This is not really a substitute for making backups and the results will be mixed.

You can check what programs will be affected when using a restore point, but it will really only detect programs that were *actually uninstalled*, not just corrupted.

Even if you (accidentally?) uninstalled Adobe Reader or Office, note that the third dialog specifically says that:

> These programs might not work correctly after restore and might need to be reinstalled

In other words, System Restore cannot be relied upon to reinstall programs even in the best of conditions because it is not a backup/restore program.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Window system restore has never been treated as a resource which can restore computer apart from certain system settings. It is not reliable in case you are having a conception that it would bring back your PC to a state where it was some days ago. This kind of backup and restore can be successfully implemented in case you have any utility like [norton ghost](http://us.norton.com/ghost), [restoret](http://www.restoret.net), acronic truecrypt installed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends what kind of System Restore you are talking about. If you made a System Restore Point, it should help a bit, but if you made a "backup and restore" type of restore, that would work better, as it will bring the system FULLY back to your last backup, instead of just a few items. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I didn't made backup or something. I am restoring with the help of restore points which Windows 7 automatically makes !