# programs removed due to a System restore

Tags: system-restore

After a system restore has occurred, is it possible to get:

1. a list of programs that have been permanently removed;
2. a list of programs that will no longer function

due to the change?

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're talking about using a System Restore Point. If that's the case, there is an option which you can select which will tell you what programs will be removed and which ones will (possibly) be effected. However, I'm not entirely sure whether this menu item is available when you let Windows automatically select a System Restore Point - I've only seen it when selected a manual point to restore back to.

Comment: You are correct http://superuser.com/a/441005/40928